# Best way to copy array(float) to local array(float)

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay so I have a structure which continuously updates in a seperate thread.

Now I need some of these variables locally somewhere without them changing in between.

I first did this to get them locally which obviously isn't the best method but it worked.

```
float MyFloatArray[3];
MyFloatArray[0] = otherThread()->floatArray[0];
MyFloatArray[1] = otherThread()->floatArray[1];
MyFloatArray[2] = otherThread()->floatArray[2];
```

Now I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

I already tried the following:

```
float MyFloatArray = otherThread()->floatArray;
float* MyFloatArray = otherThread()->floatArray; //Works but updates the otherThread array(Obviously) but that shouldn't happen
```

Since I have a decently big project it'll be a lot of work to update all these to `std::array<float,3>`

Is there any alternative? Otherwise I will update all my float arrays to `std::array<float,3>` since it's a lot cleaner if there is no alternative.

Comment: *Since I have a decently big project it'll be a lot of work to update all these to `std::array<float,3>`* this is not really showing effort to solve your problem ...

Comment: @Walter: And that's not showing any effort in helping with it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Correct, but I in their place would have done that: change do `std::array`, even if this required a little effort, it will pay out in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply call [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), making sure the copy is guarded by a synchronisation mechanism such as a `mutex`. For example:

```
std::mutex m; // otherThread() must lock this mutex when modifying array

{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
  std::copy(otherThread()->floatArray, otherThread()->floatArray + 3, MyLoatArray);
}
```

or use a copyable type, such as `std::array<float, 3>` and use assignment. Again, this has to be protected with a synchronisation mechanism:

```
std::mutex m; // otherThread() must lock this mutex when modifying array

{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
  MyFloatArray = otherThread()->floatArray;
}
```

Comment: But is the copy command a correct method or is using a copyable type as I stated already in my answer better? I've been told copy is quite a bad habbit / function to use

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit `std::copy` is a correct method and there's nothing wrong with it. Whoever told you it is a bad habit to use it should explain why they think that. But I would probably use `std::array<float, 3>` instead of a plain C array, given the choice.

Comment: None of this answer addresses the core problem that the object is being simultaneously mutated in another thread.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wow, I had managed to completely miss the actual problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an atomic copy operation. Unfortunately, that doesn't exist for entire structures, so you will have to use a *mutex* to lock accesses to the structure for the duration of your copy operation (and, in the other thread, for the duration of modifications to the structure).

Then you can either stick with your element-wise assignment, or switch to `std::copy`; it doesn't really matter. Fundamentally the latter is still going to compile down to an element-wise assignment. No matter what syntax you use, your CPU still has to copy a series of bytes and it cannot do that in a single, atomic operation. But as long as your reads and writes to the structure are protected by a mutex, you'll be fine.